# Getting different results loading SVG files from URIs

Tags: java, svg, uri, filechooser, batik

### Background

The JavaFX program MyApp will import SVG images, parse the transform and shape information from the files, and display the shapes in a class that extends the JavaFX Canvas. The part that’s giving strange results is in the initial stages, getting a file system URI for an SVG image and parsing it.

The strange part is that I have two methods of doing the same thing, but one of them works (using `FileChooser`) and the other one doesn’t (using the class loader `MyApp.class.getResource(pathString)`). Both generate a valid URI to the same file, and both URIs are fed to a batik `SAXSVGDocumentFactory`.

I’ve checked with a FileReader on both URIs to make sure that the text is read the same from both.

### Problem code (simplified)

```
FileChooser importer = new FileChooser();

URI uriBad = MyApp.class.getResource(“my_file.svg”).toURI();
URI uriGood = importer.showOpenDialog(myJavafxStage).toURI();

SAXSVGDocumentFactory documentFactory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());

SVGDocument vectorDocumentBad = documentFactory.createSVGDocument(uriBad);
SVGDocument vectorDocumentGood = documentFactory.createSVGDocument(uriGood);
```

I expected to be able to parse `vectorDocumentBad` and `vectorDocumentGood` just the same, but the transform information that I get using the same parsing function is wrong for the former document created, corresponding to `uriBad`.

### Output from bad URI

```
PARSING SVG
NODE_RootGraphicsNode without style or transform info
GROUP_RootGraphicsNode: 0.0,0.0
    GROUP_CanvasGraphicsNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: NaN,NaN
        ...
```

### Output from good URI

```
PARSING SVG
NODE_RootGraphicsNode without style or transform info
GROUP_RootGraphicsNode: 0.0,0.0
    GROUP_CanvasGraphicsNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        SHAPE_ShapeNode: 164.0199324823223,-6.723440123593414
        ...
```

### SVG Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="181.957" height="238.119"
     viewBox="0 0 181.957 238.119" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 181.957 238.119;" xml:space="preserve">

<path fill="none" stroke="#46B035" stroke-width="7" d="M58.726,11.278c0,0-2.5,4.75,2.667,16.333s12.7,13.745,12.7,13.745"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_18_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="51.5977" y1="130.6812" x2="84.5962" y2="162.1797">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_18_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="70.75" cy="148.962" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_19_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="107.0942" y1="194.0854" x2="140.0934" y2="225.5846">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_19_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="126.247" cy="212.368" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="76.2715" y1="167.9692" x2="109.2707" y2="199.4684">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_20_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="95.424" cy="186.251" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_21_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="120.1133" y1="167.0015" x2="153.1125" y2="198.5006">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_21_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="139.265" cy="185.284" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_22_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="124.1118" y1="119.4976" x2="157.111" y2="150.9967">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_22_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="143.264" cy="137.779" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_23_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="76.6772" y1="104.4282" x2="109.6764" y2="135.9274">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_23_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="95.83" cy="122.71" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_24_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="129.5947" y1="32.1802" x2="162.5939" y2="63.6793">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_24_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="148.748" cy="50.462" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_25_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="137.0527" y1="71.9644" x2="170.0519" y2="103.4635">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_25_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="156.206" cy="90.247" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_26_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="107.0933" y1="81.6763" x2="140.0924" y2="113.1754">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_26_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="126.246" cy="99.958" r="24.752"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_27_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="87.5947" y1="22.1807" x2="120.5939" y2="53.6798">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_27_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="106.748" cy="40.462" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_28_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="48.5972" y1="43.1802" x2="81.5963" y2="74.6793">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_28_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="67.75" cy="61.461" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_29_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.5986" y1="50.106" x2="39.5985" y2="81.6057">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_29_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="25.751" cy="68.388" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_30_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26.7363" y1="97.314" x2="59.7355" y2="128.8131">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_30_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="45.889" cy="115.596" r="24.751"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_31_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="102.9971" y1="46.4272" x2="135.9962" y2="77.9264">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_31_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="122.15" cy="64.709" r="24.752"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_32_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="73.0938" y1="62.1743" x2="106.0929" y2="93.6734">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_32_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="92.247" cy="80.457" r="24.752"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_33_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="37.436" y1="74.3335" x2="70.4352" y2="105.8326">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_33_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="56.589" cy="92.616" r="24.752"/>
<linearGradient id="XMLID_34_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="90.9429" y1="143.8394" x2="123.9414" y2="175.3379">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop  offset="0.736" style="stop-color:#573993"/>
</linearGradient>
<circle fill="url(#XMLID_34_)" stroke="#56278A" stroke-width="2" cx="110.095" cy="162.121" r="24.751"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#46B035" stroke-width="7" points="35.654,16.038 58.726,11.278 80.652,3.289 "/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm! The problem was not actually where I thought it was, many steps further in the method calls chain, when I was trying to modify those transform values read from the SVG file. I was basically trying to get the dimensions of a JavaFX pane that hadn’t any dimensions yet, whose undefined values where then multiplied into the SVG transforms for display.

So I was basically asking the wrong question.